# What is the difference between a Schengen visa being revoked or being annulled?

Tags: schengen, europe, terminology

What is the difference between revoked and annulled Schengen visa? Does it means the same thing, or are they separate?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk nice one, thanks for the speedy lookup too.

Comment: This is being marked as a duplicate because our local Schengen expert (@Relaxed) gave an impeccably accurate definition. If it does not answer your question, then edit your question to be clear and then click the 'reopen' button, thanks

Comment: @GayotFow Although the answer in Relaxed's answer clearly covers this issue, the heading for that question will not naturally lead one to believe it is the same as this one.

Comment: @SheikPaul nice one. Fixed, try it now

Comment: @SheikPaul you can undelete your answer and tart it up a bit also

Comment: @SheikPaul +1 for a well composed answer. consider moving your answer into the 'canonical' link above.

Answer (score 1):

[**The annulment and revocation of visa**](http://www.legalsl.com/en/the-annulment-and-revocation-of-the-visa.htm)

> According to the Regulation (EC) No. 810/2009 of the European
>   Parliament and of the Council (the cd. Visa Code), a visa shall be
>   **annulled** where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it **were not met at the time when it was issued**, in particular if
>   there are serious grounds for believing that the visa was fraudulently
>   obtained.
>
> A visa shall in principle be annulled by the competent authorities of
>   the Member State which issued it. A visa may be annulled by the
>   competent authorities of another Member State, in which case the
>   authorities of the Member State that issued the visa shall be informed
>   of such annulment.
>
> A visa shall be **revoked** where it becomes evident that **the
>   conditions for issuing it are no longer met**. A visa shall in
>   principle be revoked by the competent authorities of the Member State
>   which issued it. A visa may be revoked by the competent authorities of
>   another Member State, in which case the authorities of the Member
>   State that issued the visa shall be informed of such revocation.

Neither an annulment nor a revocation legally bar an applicant from receiving a visa in the future and both can happen without any implication that the holder of the visa did anything wrong. It may sometimes simply be on a technicality.